# Fill rectangle with pattern in Java Swing

Tags: java, swing, graphics, 2d, design-patterns

I know how to fill a rectangle in Swing with a solid color:

```
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
g2d.fillRect(0,0,100,100);
```

I know how to fill it with an image:

```
BufferedImage bi;
Graphics2D g2d = bi.createGraphics();
g2d.setPaint (new Color(r, g, b));
g2d.fillRect (0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight());
```

But how to fill rectangle of size 950x950 with some tiled pattern of size 100x100?

*(pattern image should be used 100 times)*

Comment: put every elements to the array (in proper ordering), then loop inside array

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable

Comment: Have you tried using a [TexturePaint](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html) object for this?

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels No, I haven't known about it, thank you!

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You're on the right track with `setPaint`. However, instead of setting it to a color, you want to set it to a [`TexturePaint`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html) object.

From [the Java tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/strokeandfill.html):

> The pattern for a TexturePaint class is defined by a BufferedImage class. To create a TexturePaint object, you specify the image that contains the pattern and a rectangle that is used to replicate and anchor the pattern. The following image represents this feature:
>   [image: example image]

If you have a `BufferedImage` for the texture, create a `TexturePaint` like so:

```
TexturePaint tp = new TexturePaint(myImage, new Rectangle(0, 0, 16, 16));
```

where the given rectangle represents the area of the source image you want to tile.

The constructor JavaDoc is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/TexturePaint.html#TexturePaint%28java.awt.image.BufferedImage,%20java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D%29).

Then, run

```
g2d.setPaint(tp);
```

and you're good to go.

Comment: is it possible to randomize the positions a little bit?

Comment: @wutzebaer Not with a texture paint, no. There isn't a concept of "positions" (of, presumably, the circles); the circles are just part of the image, which gets tiled. If you actually want this specific pattern but with randomized circles, you could draw it procedurally: first fill your canvas with the background color, then fill rows of circles, and perturb them slightly from the nominal positions.

Answer (score 3):

As @wchargin said, you can use `TexturePaint`. Here is an example:

```
public class TexturePanel extends JPanel {

    private TexturePaint paint;

    public TexturePanel(BufferedImage bi) {
        super();
        this.paint = new TexturePaint(bi, new Rectangle(0, 0, bi.getWidth(), bi.getHeight()));
    }

    @Override
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
        g2.setPaint(paint);
        g2.fill(new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight()));
    }
}
```